# How to get all defined secrets in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to print all defined secrets (or at least their keys) in a `gitlab_ci.yml` script?

Pseudocode:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: |
          for KEY in $SECRETS
             echo $KEY
          done
```

Comment: Would using the `env` command work? If not, why not?

Comment: @sytech could you give an example how to?

Answer (score 1):

I believe getting the secrets alone is only possible if you already know which secrets exist in the pipeline. But in most images, such as the default ruby image, the `env` command exists, which lists all env variables, both key and value.
All secrets should be contained within these variables, or at least be listed as a file from within there.

If you have control over how the secrets are named, you can also achieve your original result of only getting secrets, by filtering them. For instance, if you can name every secret with a postfix like `_SECRET`, you could call

```sh
env | grep _SECRET=
```

and if, as in your original example you only want to list the values, you can call:

```sh
env | grep _SECRET= | cut -d = -f2-
```

Comment: That's a start at least. But it's probably not possible to find only keys that have been added by the gitlab-cicd variables configuration page?

Comment: Yes, it's doesn't seem possible, at least doing it automatically. You could of course still keep a list of variables that are being set in your gitlab-ci file, or in the cicd variables page, that keeps track of the variables you want to iterate over